# How to Count Number of Items in List Within RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD and each row has the following structure:

```
[(id,[listItem,listItem,ListItem])]
```

I have to go through the entire RDD and count the amount of list items. I've tried something like this:

```
theCount = 0
theRDD.foreach(lambda x: theCount = theCount + x[1].count())
return theCount
```

but Python doesn't let me assign a value to `theCount` within the lambda function. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sc.parallelize([('id', [1, 2, 3])]).map(lambda tup: (tup[0], len(tup[1]))).collect()
```

Output

```
[('id', 3)]
```

Spark doesn't send local variables across the job, throughout the cluster (even if running on a single, local node). That's why the syntax you have isn't possible.

Comment: That's Great! But how do I sum the values of the second column to retrieve the sum of all the lists?

Comment: Sound like a secondary question that you should make a new post for after you accept this one since it answered the question. Comments are for clarification on what was posted, not "Thanks", or "What if I want..."

Comment: Sorry, I thought I made it clear when constructing this question. Here is the link to the second part of this question:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705596/how-to-sum-values-of-column-within-rdd)

Comment: Your comment was clear, but your question said amount of the items in the list, not sum of the items.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps,

```
from operator import add

lst = [1,3,5,7,9]
print("{}".format(len(lst)))

ps_lst = sc.parallelize(lst)
print("{}".format(ps_lst.map(lambda x: 1).reduce(add)))
```

5
5

Comment: Simple and brilliant! Thanks