# How to Sum values of Column Within RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD with the following rows:

```
[(id,value)]
```

How would you sum the values of all rows in the RDD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`sum`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.sum), you just need to get the data into a list.

For example

```
sc.parallelize([('id', [1, 2, 3]), ('id2', [3, 4, 5])]) \ 
    .flatMap(lambda tup: tup[1]) \ # [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
    .sum()
```

Outputs 18

Similarly, just use `values()` to get that second column as an RDD on it's own.

```
sc.parallelize([('id', 6), ('id2', 12)]) \ 
    .values() \ # [6, 12]
    .sum()
```

Comment: Why bother with fold if there is sum?

Comment: @zero323 Habit to be more verbose, I guess :)