# Spark - calculating sum of all the values in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark (learning phase).

I have an RDD with a single column which has following values :

```
5000
6000
7000
8000
9000
```

Now I want to calculate the sum of all the values without using Spark SQL.

I have tried many ways to solve this, but couldn't really solve it.

> val rdd2 = rdd1.map(agg(sum()))
>
> val rdd2 = rdd1.map(c => sum(col(c)))
>
> val rdd2 = rdd1.collect().sum()

I can assure you this is not a duplicate question, I searched through the all related questions but did not find any similar question. whoever thinks that its a duplicate question please request you to read the question again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can at least try to post what you have tried from those "many ways" ?

Comment: And : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705596/how-to-sum-values-of-column-within-rdd?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @eliasah what I tried is not giving at all any useful output, so didn't post.

Comment: @Sankar It doesn't matter if it didn't work. Post it anyway. Also read [do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions) and [mcve] to know why.

Comment: I added what I tried, i know what i tried wasn't very clever that is why did not want to post. Is it really a duplicate one? I do not think so, here i already have the RDD, and I want to sum the RDD contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is literally `sum`:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> rdd.sum
res0: Double = 35000.0
```

Comment: The problem is i already have the values in an RDD